# How to Update Date in each row with different dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I want to update date column of the table with dates in the increment of 1 for all rows.

How do I do it in MySQL?

Table: tbl_question_of_the_day
Column: date

So the output that I want is:

Row 1: Today

Row 2: Tomorrow

Row 3: Day after tomorrow
...and so on.

There is an ID column as primary key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to have the following:

| id | date | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 | There is no spoon. |
| 2 | 2021-05-27 | I know kung fu. |
| 3 | 2021-05-28 | zOMG! A Nokia 8801! |
| 4 | 2021-05-29 | Anything you'd like, Mr. Reagan. |
| 5 | 2021-05-30 | Follow the white rabbit. |
| 6 | 2021-05-31 | Not like this. |

... then I would suggest taking a look at [the `DATE_ADD()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) and using the `id` value as the `INTERVAL` amount.

Comment: Thanks for this. But how will the Update statement look like? I understand I might have to do some kind of looping I guess.

Comment: There is almost no reason to *ever* do a loop when working with data like this. I would strongly recommend taking a look at Stack Overflow to see how `UPDATE` statements are generally written, as that site is probably better geared towards these sorts of questions

Comment: Ok..Thank you for your suggestions.